# salesforce certification payment is possible with debit card?

Tags: certification

Salesforce certification payment process  is possible with debit card?

could anyone reply

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes. As you're registering, you'll enter your payment type. You can enter a voucher/coupon code and/or credit card. This also includes a debit card.

I've paid by this method myself. :)